# ESLint couldn't find the config "standard" to extend from

Tags: typescript, eslint

When I try to lint as `eslint --ext .ts "./**/*.ts" --fix` following error has occured.

```
MAC0157:shop-api $ npm run lint

> shop-api@1.0.0 lint
> eslint --ext .ts "./**/*.ts" --fix


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.24.0

ESLint couldn't find the config "standard" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "standard" was referenced from the config file in "/Users/post-pricing/.eslintrc.json".

If you still have problems, please stop by https://eslint.org/chat/help to chat with the team.
```

my `.eslintrc.json` is like follows.

`.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "standard",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "no-useless-constructor": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        "vars": "all",
        "args": "after-used",
        "ignoreRestSiblings": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

I searched this root cause. but I still have this issue.
Are there any ways to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the "standard" configuration you're trying to extend? It seems like it doesn't exist - do you have to install it or link it separately?

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't install `eslint-config-standard`:

```
npm install eslint-config-standard
```